# How to say in FOL that P(f) is true and everything else with property P is false?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

How to say in FOL:

1. "francis" is "Pope"
2. Nothing is identical to "francis"
3. Except for "francis", is false that something is "Pope"

The formula should imply that:

1. $P(f)$ is TRUE
2. $P(f)$ is NOT IDENTICAL to $P(g), P(h), P(i)$ etc.
3. $P(g), P(h), P(i)$ etc. are FALSE

I think this is not satisfying:

$$P(f)∧∀x(P(x)→f=x)$$

because it doesn't imply that $P(g), P(h)$ etc. are false, only that they are identical to $P(f)$.

Comment: 2 is $\lnot \exists x (x=f)$

Comment: 3 is fine......

Comment: Thanks. Should I edit the post? (I'm new to this platform, and not an expert in logic)

Comment: The problem i see with $\neg \exists x (x=f) \equiv \forall x (x \neq f)$ is that we have a contradiction whenever we instantiate $x$ with $f$. In other words, $f$ is an element of the domain, so we obtain $f \neq f$ whenever we instantiate $x$ with $f$.

Comment: You are welcome :-) and yes, you can.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy yes. I think this is the point

Comment: so @FMG wants to construct a sentence that is always false?

Comment: I want to construct a sentence that makes true P(f) and false everything else with property P, and I can't see how

Comment: Because "f" is always included in "for every x", no matter how you use quantifiers or identity. This is probably my fault. But still I can't see why.

Comment: Maybe the question is: can you say something like "everything else" or "everything except this" in FOL?

Comment: @FMG $P(f) \wedge \forall x [f \neq x \to \neg P(x)]$ quite literally states "$P$ is true for $f$ and $P$ is false for anything that is not $f$." This implies that $f$ is the one and only element that $P$ is true for. The only way $P(g)$ could be true is if $f=g$, in which case there is no issue because $g$ and $f$ are the very same object. So really $P(g)$ is just $P(f)$ whenever $f=g$. but this does not seem to satisfy you.

Comment: Ok. Imagine that you are trying to solve a riddle. You are a detective, you have 3 suspects (a, b, c), only one is the killer. So you are using this rule: "if one is the killer, nobody else is the killer". In FOL, you can say: "if Ka then not Kb, if Ka then not Kc, if Kb then not Ka, if Kb then..." and so on.

Comment: Now, different scenario: you have infinite supects. You can't say "if Ka then not..." for infinite suspects. How can you say that infinite suspects are not the killer, except for one? Your formula is not useful, because it says: "all the suspects, if they are the killer, are the same one person". If you are suspecting two killers at the same time, Ka and Kb, you can't find the contradiction, because you don't have a formal rule to exclude that Ka and Kb are the same person.

Comment: As a result, you have Ka true, Kb true, Kc true, etc... Thay are all killers, and all the same person. How can you state: "a" is K, nobody else is identical to "a", and nobody else is K?

Comment: @FMG You can't. If you could, then adding a new symbol $a'$ and interpreting it as having the same value as $a$ would make the statement false when it was originally true, but by induction on formulas you can prove that adding a new symbol like this can't change the truth value of any formula. The thing that you're asking for is a property of the language, and FOL can only express properties of the objects.

Comment: Or if you *are* asking for a property of the objects, then it's a property that's already always true. Any two distinct objects are not equal, because that's what "distinct" and "equal" mean. "Anything that is not equal to $a$ is not equal to $a$" is a tautology, and having multiple different symbols that refer to the same thing does not imply that that thing is not equal to itself.

Comment: @pastebee interesting. (It's my limit, but I still struggle to understand the reason. I'll try to find out more)

Answer (score 0):

In FOL, if you want to express there is exactly one element in the given domain with property $P$, then we write

$$ \exists y [P(y) \wedge \forall x [P(x) \to y=x] ] $$

Now, if you want to identify the unique element with property $P$ as Francis, abbreviated as $f$, then we let $y=f$ and apply existential instantation to obtain

$$ P(f) \wedge \forall x [P(x) \to f=x] ] $$

**which does in fact imply that $P(g), P(h)$, etc. are false statements**. To see how, let $x=g$ where $g$ is an individual constant corresponding to someone who is *not* Francis, say Gary. In other words, let $x=g$ where $f \neq g$. Now, assume the statement $P(g)$ is true. Then, by Modus Ponens we obtain $f=g$, implying Francis and Gary are the same person. But we have already stated $f \neq g$. Hence, we have a contradiction. Since we obtain a contradiction under the assumption $P(g)$ is true, it must be the case $P(g)$ is false.

Note the above formula can be written equivalently as

$$ P(f) \wedge \forall x [f \neq x \to \neg P(x)] ] $$

Comment: Thank you. I don't think that with f=g we obtain a contradiction. Formally, f and g can be the same person ("gary" can be another name for "francis"), so the formula doesn't imply NOT P(g) (or NOT P(h), NOT P(i) etc).

Comment: I think you skipped over the part where i said "let $x=g$ where $g$ is an individual constant corresponding to someone who is *not* Francis." Hence, Gary cannot be just another name for Francis. Anytime you substitute $x$ with a person who is not Francis, you will get a contradiction, implying Francis is the one and only person for which $P$ is true.

Comment: I didn't skip, but I think you can't freely assume the value of g, it must be stated in the formula. Otherwise, g and f could be the same person (that is exactly the problem).

Comment: It's probably my fault. But I think the formula should imply NOT P(g) independently by the value of g, that we don't know. The fact that g is not f should be a consequence of the formula, not a starting point. Of course, if we start saying that g is not the same of f, the result is that g is not the same. But I'm saying: we don't know what is g, and we want to state that P(f) is true and everything else with the property P is false.

Comment: Either $f=g$ or $f \neq g$. If $f=g$, then there is no contradiction. In other words, if $f$ and $g$ are the same person, then $P(g)$ does not imply something else with property $P$ is true... because $f$ and $g$ are the same person! On the other hand, if $f \neq g$, then we have a contradiction. This ensures that **everything else** with the property $P$ is false.

Comment: I see. I asked is that the formula should imply: P(f) is true, f must be not identical to anything else (g, h, i...), P(g) or P(h) or P(i) must be false. If you assume that g is different from f, the problem is simple. But it must be a consequence, not

Comment: (sorry) ...a starting point.

Comment: If we have infinitely many constants g, h, i, ..., then we cannot express "f is not identical to any of g, h, I, .." in a single FOL sentence